# Install Findsecbugs plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs

I have installed  FindBugs plugin version 3.0.1 for Eclipse Mars.   I am trying to get the  FindSecBugs 1.4.1 plugin to work.  I don't have internet access.  I have the  FindSecBugs jar.   I am unsure of where to put the jar file and if anything else needs to be done.

Answer (score 3):

Just put it anywhere on your filesystem, open Window->Preferences->Java->FindBugs->Plugins and misc. Settings and use "Add..." button there:

[image: add FindBugs plugin]